# Unable to send JSON Raw via Post Request

Tags: android, json, http-post

Here is my POST Json i have to pass data from android app can any one please help me to

```
{  
   "book":{  
      "details":{  
         "detail":[  
            {  
               "title":"Ms"
            }
         ]
      },
      "contact_detail":{  
         "mobile_number":"9888888888"
      }
   },
   "origin_id":"134"
}
```

And my android code

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection=null;
        String json = null;
        try {
            HttpResponse response;
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
             jsonObject.accumulate("origin_id", "134");
            jsonObject.accumulate("mobile_number", "9888888888");

            jsonObject.accumulate("title", "Ms");
            json = jsonObject.toString();
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(json, "UTF-8"));
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            httpPost.addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
           // httpPost.setHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US");
            response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            String sresponse = response.getEntity().toString();
            Log.w("QueingSystem", json);
            Log.w("QueingSystem", sresponse);
            Log.w("QueingSystem", EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());

        } finally {
    /* nothing to do here */
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Getting an error output 
{"response":{"code":400,"message":"Not a valid Json"}}
Unable to can any one please help me

Comment: `{"prop" : "val",}` is not valid json neither `["a", "b",]`

Comment: Check your web service servers logs. That might reveal whats going on.

Comment: @LoveForDroid Is showing Not a Valid Json

Answer (score 0):

I validated the JSON you given, it is correct.

I look through your coding on the POST, however did you the actual JSON through or are using

> ~            jsonObject.accumulate("origin_id", "134");
>               jsonObject.accumulate("mobile_number", "9888888888");

Your approach could be simplified, nevertheless. If you insert log statement before and after the EndPoints, it will pinpoint what java objects are carrying what values for you.